# Unable to locate some packages for installing python on ubuntu terminal in windows

Tags: python, ubuntu

SOLVED!!

im following a tutorial video from my bootcamp (open course, i cant ask the teachers) but im really stuck, beacuse im doing all step by step, and i have this error, i dont know how to solve, i hope anyone can help me. The error is this:

(((((this is my line command)))))
galgodev@DESKTOP-TCAV24S:~/.pyenv$ sudo apt-get install -y build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev libbz2-dev \ libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev wget curlo llvm libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev \ xz-tuils tk-dev libffi-dev liblzma-dev python-openssl git

(((((this is my line command)))))

(((((this is the error)))))

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done

E: Unable to locate package  libreadline-dev

E: Unable to locate package curlo

E: Unable to locate package  xz-tuils

galgodev@DESKTOP-TCAV24S:~/.pyenv$

(((((this is the error)))))

the video tutorial i was following is this: https://player.vimeo.com/video/489725118 exactly in the minute 34:45, i hope anyone can help me :C

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running the command without `\`s?

Also you can try running `sudo apt-get update` before you run the command?

For future, also please format your text with '`' characters to make it look nice:)

Comment: thank you for the comment, but im trying without the / s, and i update, but nothing happened, you have any other idea?

Comment: i solved!!! i dont know who xD, anyway thanks so much for the help

Comment: if you found the solution, then you should share it in a comment so someone else has the same question then they can solve it